# Is there any way to call IIFE function on button click?

Tags: javascript, function, iife

There is a generated IIFE function inside script tag from CRM, and I need to call this function on button click, is there any way to do this?

```js
<script data-b24-form="click/18/3h30a2" data-skip-moving="true">
(function(w,d,u){
                var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/180000|0);
                var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
        })(window,document,'https://');        
</script>
```

Comment: No. If what you want is a function that you can call later, do not use an IIFE.

Comment: If so it wouldn't be a **immediately invoked** function expression but instead be a regular function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, if that code is automatically generated and you can't do anything to change it.

The function is never saved anywhere, it's just run once and then discarded. Since it's never saved anywhere, there's nothing you can use to call it.

If you could change the code, then of course you could save the function and use it in your click handler:

```
<script data-b24-form="click/18/3h30a2" data-skip-moving="true">
// Create the function without calling it, store it in `theFunction`
var theFunction = function(w,d,u){
                var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/180000|0);
                var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
        }.bind(window, window,document,'https://');
theFunction(); // The initial call
// In your click handler, call `theFunction`.
</script>
```

Comment: This script is not getting generated on page load, I have this script ready but the problem is that I have tons of pages and each page has a button and I need to call this IIFE function on button click instead of putting this script on every pages, I want to put this script in footer or external js file with named function so that I can call this function on button click. When I am using your above function it is throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: d.createElement is not a function`

Comment: @AzeemAnsari - I've fixed the call to `bind` above. The above shows you how to make the function callable. A web search for how to hook up a click event should tell you everything else you need to know.